# MS Access Web App: corrupted table, cannot open in Access anymore

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

**tldr: How can I delete a corrupted table that prevents me from opening my Web App in Access?**

I used the Access desktop client to create a new table with approx 20 lookup fields. When I tried saving the table, I received an error message about too many indices. So I set the index option to "no" for all the lookup fields and tried to close the "edit table view". However, I was not able to close the edit table view anymore. After trying for a while, I used the task manager to terminate Access.
Now, when I try to open my app in Access by clicking the "customize in Access" button on the web, I receive several error messages:

1. Operation failed: the table xxx contains too many indices. Delete some indices and try again. (this error message appears about 5 times)
2. Microsoft Access can not create the table
3. A problem occurred when trying to access a property or method of the OLE object.
   Next, I'm at the Access start screen. My application does not open.

So, is there any other way I can delete the corrupted table without opening it through the Access client? Maybe directly accessing the SQL server? The database is configured to allow read/write connections, becasue I connected to the tables from an Access Desktop Database, but I'm not sure if I can delete a table or fields that way. Any help is greatly appreciated!

[I translated the error messages from German, so they might be slightly different in the English version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work with the Access product team and I asked them about your specific issue. For your particular issue, it can be solved however you will need to open a support service request via the Office 365 service request channel. If you are using Office 365, there should be an admin entry point where you can open a service request. Our engineers will then work to get you unblocked so you can open the Access 2013 web app again within the client design surface.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. I have submitted a ticket on Office 365. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Hi, would you be willing to share the service ticket number with me? I'm trying to locate this in the system to make sure it gets routed right to our product team. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Jeff, that will be very helpful. I talked to a support engineer on Friday, but he wasn't able to solve the problem just yet. The ticket # is 114111490702916. Thanks!

Comment: Great, thank you for the number; that's just what we needed. Our support engineers should be in touch with you very shortly and will be reviewing the other engineer's notes.

Comment: Support solved the problem! :) My ticket was escalated to the Access development team, they deleted some fields in the corrupted table and now my App is accessible again. Thanks Jeff!

Comment: Excellent, that's great to hear. Thanks for posting back here and updating the group. I've been checking on your ticket status so it was good to see that you are now unblocked.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to create a completely new Access database. Go into the new database, and run the Import > Access process. This will allow you to browse and find the corrupt database. When the dialog opens, select all objects except the corrupt one. So bring in all of your forms (if any), tables, code, queries, etc. This now becomes your main DB and you can delete the other.

Have you tried running the built-in Compact/Repair process?

Kindest regards...

Comment: Daniel, unfortunately your solution will not work for this scenario. The customer is using an Access 2013 web app. You cannot import objects from a 2013 web app into a new desktop database container. The 2013 web app stores everything in a SQL database so you can't import objects in the more traditional fashion. There is also no Compact/Repair option for 2013 web apps.

Comment: Sorry. I did not realize it was a web app.