# MS Access Web App: restore snapshot (backup) on same site as current version?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, ms-access-2013

*Background: I am developing a small Accees Web App for my organization. It is hosted on our Office 365 SharePoint.  There is no professional development environment and there are no plans for proper deployment. I am developing the app and maintaining data at the same time. A handful of people will eventually use the web UI to maintain data.*

During development (which went hand in hand with data imports) I have made backups of the App including data using the "Save as Snapshot" function. I have not changed the name of the App when saving snapshots.

Now I want to restore the snapshot package (backup), because I have a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907417/ms-access-web-app-corrupted-table-cannot-open-in-access-anymore) with the current version of the App. However, I also want keep the current version of the app for comparison. So basically I want to duplicate my App.

When I try creating a new Access App on the SharePoint site and choose to upload the backup .app package, I get an error message saying

> The provided App differs from another App with the same version and product ID

I tried unzipping the .app package of my backup an changing the version number in AppManifest.xml, but still got the same error message.

Is there any way to upload the backup package under another name/product ID without deleting the current version?

And a more general question, what would be the best ways to backup the App including data during development and use?

Answer (score 0):

The rule is that on a subscription the combination of GUID and Version Number must be unique, but you can have the same GUID and different Version numbers on different subsites. So after cracking open the package and changing the version number upload it to a different subsite.